# dnf update: Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success. (all mirror 404)

Tags: centos, redhat, repository, checksum, dnf

I am trying to execute the `dnf update` command on almalinux 8.7
Before a few hours it worked properly, now all mirror gives 404.

I examined the urls, and it seems, that in all repo the checksum in urls are changed.

For example `dnf update` is trying the url

```
http://ftp.bme.hu/almalinux/8.7/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/86ea74b2f08c662d45b1405f50f1f0e6ba8f07256801ff3d443f3bc8f870003b-primary.xml.gz
```

but when I browse the http://ftp.bme.hu/almalinux/8.7/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/ in browser I see that the name of `primary.xml.g` is changed to

```
http://ftp.bme.hu/almalinux/8.7/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/f6123897b49409e61805a802d5fe4aeab34e682798fbf28b79d0b811e0f24025-primary.xml.gz
```

and the change date is within a few hours. The content of `http://ftp.bme.hu/almalinux/8.7/BaseOS/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml` changed accordingly.

**Question**

How can I refresh my dnf/yum to use the new urls?
I have tried to `dnf clean all`, `dnf distro sync`, then `dnf update` the issue remains.